# PHP Specials foreach multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I got array like this

```
$specials = array( 1 => array('word' => array('first', 'two', 'three'), 'digit' => array(1,2,3)),
                   2 => array('word' => array('four','five', 'six'), 'digit' => array(4,5,6)), 
                   3 => array('word' => array('seven', 'eight', 'nine'), 'digit' => array(7,8,9)),
                   4 => array('word' => array('ten','eleven', 'twelve'), 'digit' => array(10,11,12)) 
                   );
```

and why i got to foreach 3 times like this

```
foreach($specials as  $val) {
    foreach($val as $valData) {
        foreach($valData as $value) {
            echo $value.'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

But how to loop or foreach correctly and with their index name like this ?

```
echo $value['word'];
echo $value['digit'];
```

i got error warning if `echo $value['digit']`

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'digit' in ~/public_html/test/array.php on line 58
```

i need those output for different HTML and CSS each Value

`<div class="digit"><?=$value['digit']?></div>
<div class="word"><?=$value['word']?></div>`

Comment: What is your question/problem ? What is your current output and what would you expect ?

Comment: i need to echo different index name , echo $value['word'] or $value['digit'] not $value as example above

Comment: What do you mean with: *different index name* ? Please add your current output into your question + the expected output

Comment: how to echo $value['digit'] ?

Comment: What should `$value["digit"]` even output?

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'digit' in ~/public_html/test/array.php on line 51

Comment: ^ If this is what it should print that you already have your correct output, because you don't have an inner Array from `$value` and so there also can't be an index named `digit`. Your question is very unclear

Comment: i need to use it add different style of html <div class="digit"><?=$value['digit']?></div> and <div class="word"><?=$value['word']?></div>

Comment: what `$value['digit']` and `$value['word']` should print?

Comment: Since 'digit' and 'word' are both arrays themselves, it doesn't make sense to echo `$value['word']` directly.

Comment: echo $value['digit'] is got warning and error as above i told you

Comment: Read again all the comments please, then try again to answer questions

Comment: @coder5 As I already said like 10 comments above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552327/php-specials-foreach-multidimensional-array#comment49176834_30552327 Add what your current output is and what you would expect to get

Comment: my expect output is simple, i use for html css class <div class="digit"><?=$value['digit']?></div> and <div class="word"><?=$value['word']?></div>

Comment: @coder5 Please fill in the `...` fields in the following text: 1) My current output of the shown code above is ... ? 2) My expected output of the sown code above is ... ? 3) I expect from `$value['word']` to get the value ... ? <- Add all these things into your question

Comment: @Leggendario Patience my friend :) If I learned on thing on SO then you need a lot of patience.

Comment: thanks all read the answer below  @John McMahon already try another simple solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($specials as  $val) {
    foreach($val as $key => $valData) {
        // $key is now either 'word' or 'digit'
        foreach($valData as $value) {
            echo "<div class='$key'>$value</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't do that .. coz i need to use different style of html and css <div class="digit"><?=$value['digit']?></div> and <div class="word"><?=$value['word']?></div>

Comment: @coder5 Since we don't know what your final output is supposed to look like, why couldn't you use the `$key` value in the above example for css classes?

Comment: ok thats , great solution , why many comments just asking arround and not give me the answer :'(

Comment: @coder5 *why many comments* Because your question is very unclear.

Comment: i already edit the question coz i need different style HTML or CSS class each value :'(

Comment: @coder5 It's simple fill in the gabs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552327/php-specials-foreach-multidimensional-array#comment49177129_30552327 That's what you should have done and what you should have added to your question to make it clear

Comment: ok please tell me how to ask in correct english ? so people can understand and can use it in certain situation like mine ?

Comment: ok @rizier123 i edit more clear question and please upvote my question so i got little point :)

Comment: @coder5 1. What do you expect from: `$value['word']` as output to get, 42 ? 2. Is *those output* your current output or your expected output ?!

Comment: John McMahon give me the correct output what i need exactly

Comment: @coder5 He played Russian roulette and made a guess and hoped, that he guessed correctly what you want, but he also could have been wrong. So your question stays unclear and you may get downvoted.

Comment: @Rizier123 I had a feeling the gun wasn't loaded ;)